# mount error 5 = Input/output error

Tags: debian, debian-lenny, cifs, smbfs

I am running out of ideas.  After a long period of testing this morning, I cannot seem to get this to work, and I have no idea why.  I want to mount a Windows SMB/CIFS share with a Debian 5.0.4 VM, and it is not cooperating.

This the command I am using.

> **debianvm:/home/me#** whoami
>
> root
>
> **debianvm:/home/me#** smbclient --version
>
> Version 3.2.5
>
> **debianvm:/home/me#** mount -t cifs //hostname.domain.tld/share /mnt/hostname.domain.tld/share --verbose -o user=SUBADDOMAIN.ADDOMAIN.DOMAIN.TLD/username
>
> mount.cifs kernel mount options:
> unc=//hostname.domain.tld\share,ip=10.212.15.53,domain=SUBADDOMAIN.ADDOMAIN.DOMAIN.TLD,ver=1,rw,user=username,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,pass=*******************mount
>
> error 5 = Input/output error Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g.man mount.cifs)
>
> **debianvm:/home/me#**

The word on the nets has not been very specific, and unfortunately it is almost always environment-specific.  I receive no authentication errors.  I have tried `mount -t smbfs` and `mount -t cifs`, along with `smbmount` and such.  I get the same error before.  I doubt it is a problem with DNS resolution, because logging shows the correct IP address. `dmesg | tail -f` no longer shows authentication errors when I format the domain and username accordingly.  I have played a little with `iocharset=utf8`, `file_mode`, and `dir_mode` as described [here](http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/mounting-windows-smb-file-shares-using-cifs).  That did not help either.  I have also tried `ntlm` and `ntlmv2` assuming it might be a minimum auth method problem, but not forcing `sec=ntlmv2` it can still authenticate without errors anymore.  `smbclient -L hostname.domain.tld -W SUBADDOMAIN.ADDOMAIN.DOMAIN.TLD -U username` correctly lists all the shares and shows it as the following.

```
    Domain=[SUBADDOMAIN] OS=[Windows 5.0] Server=[Windows 2000 LAN Manager]

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
IPC$            IPC       Remote IPC
ETC$            Disk      Remote Administration
C$              Disk      Remote Administration 
Share           Disk      

Connection to hostname.domain.tld failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
NetBIOS over TCP disabled -- no workgroup available
```

I find the last line intriguing/alarming.  Does anyone have any pointers!?  Maybe I misread the effin manual.

Comment: Couple questions that may or may not help: IS the VM network in bridged or NAT mode? Can you mount this share from a windows box that is not a member of the domain? Is there AD security policy preventing this box from authenticating? Anything in the fileserver or DC logs?

Comment: IS the VM network in bridged or NAT mode? Bridged. Can you mount this share from a windows box that is not a member of the domain? Yes, a Windows PE instance running on a laptop behind me. Is there AD security policy preventing this box from authenticating? Anything in the fileserver or DC logs? Alas, I do not have access to such things.  I am a lower admin on the totem pole.

Comment: Have you tried adding workgroup=workgroupname to the mount command?

Comment: Have you tried adding it directly to fstab? //domain.ltd/share /mountpoint/folder cifs username=yourusername,password=yourpassword 0 0 after that executing # mount -a ?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use SMB 1.0, which may very well be disabled by default now.

Can you use ver=3.0, which specifies SMB version 3.0.

You really should just ask your SMB admins what the minimum requirements are, as they may well have been elevated.

What is the version of the SMB server you are talking to?

Comment: Sadly long since left the environment where I had this issue. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which solved me my problem:

Try a different sec option. My Debian default reside in `/proc/fs/cifs/SecurityFlags` is `0x81`, (digging in: https://www.kernel.org/doc/readme/fs-cifs-README didnt resolved what the `0x80` mean).
Nevertheless after trying some security option, it worked for me with `-osec=ntlm`.

Worth a shot.